# Como puedo poner tamaño a una columna HTML

Tags: html, html5

Trabajo en html tengo la nesescidad que todas las celdas que están en una columna tengan el mismo ancho tengo el siguiente código pero no lo he podido conseguir

```
<body>


 <table border="1" width="100%">
  <caption>Ejemplo de tabla</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <th style="display: block; width: 100%;"></th>  <!-- Los th son los encabezados -->
      <th colspan="8">Lengua y Literatura</th>
      <th colspan="8">Matemática</th>
      <th colspan="8">Entorno Natural y Social</th>
      <th colspan="8">Educación Cultural y Artistica</th>
      <th colspan="8">Educación Física</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 120px" >
      <th></th> <!-- Las celdas se encriben dentro de td -->
      <td >Apellidos y Nombres</td>
      <td><p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(180deg);">Investigaciones <br> Tarea</Tarea> </p></td>
      <td><p style="float: left; text-align: left; writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(180deg);">Individuales <br> Actividades </p></td>
      <td><p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(180deg);">Grupales <br> Actividades </p></td>
      <td><p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(180deg);">Lecciones</p></td>
      <td><p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(180deg);">Promedio</p></td>
      <td><p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(180deg);">E. Sumativa</p></td>
      <td style="background-color: gray;"><p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(180deg);">PROMEDIO</p></td>
      <td style="background-color: gray;"><p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(180deg);">E. Cualitativa</p></td>
      <!-- Segundo -->
```

El  donde se encuentra apellidos y nombres debe tener un ancho en el cual se pueda ingresar cierto datos.

[image: Apellidos y Nombres]

Con el tamaño que se muestra en la imagen es muy pequeña, como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Asigna ancho en pixeles y no lo conviertas en bloque: `<th style="width:200px"></th>`

Comment: @Triby No hace cambio alguno, es el lugar adecuado para que cambie el tamaño de toda la columna?

Comment: @Triby si funciono pero tuve que poner el siguiente código en ´<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;" border=1>´

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con poner un ancho en píxeles, ya que ahí está tomando el 100% de su capacidad, si le ponex PX, va a romper el molde establecido en %.
Prueba con:

```
<th style="width:350px"></th>
```

Comment: No hay cambio alguno, es el lugar adecuado para que toda la columna tenga el mismo tamaño?